# How will I display values from arduino to JTextArea (Java Netbeans)?

Tags: arduino-uno, display, java

I want to display float values in JTextArea but it doesn't show any. It only displays on the systemout. Pls help me out. This is my Java code.

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

    public ards() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(319, 319, 319)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(140, 140, 140)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(157, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         String str;

        //In the constructor pass the name of the port with which we work
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM6");

        try {
            //Open port
            serialPort.openPort();

            //We expose the settings. You can also use this line - serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);



            Thread.sleep(1000);//Very important !!!



            //Read data from port
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                str = serialPort.readString();

                if (str != null) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                   jTextArea1.setText(str);
                    jLabel2.setText(str);
                }

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            //Closing the port
            serialPort.closePort();

        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ards.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ards.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ards.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ards.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ards().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And this is my Arduino code

```
const int model = 0;   
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

float sensitivity[] ={
0.185, // for ACS712ELCTR-05B-T
0.100, // for ACS712ELCTR-20A-T
0.066 // for ACS712ELCTR-30A-T } ;

void loop() {  
static unsigned long count=0;
static float Vsum=0;
float Vave=0;
int volt = analogRead(A1);
float voltage= map(volt,0,1023, 0, 2500)/100.0;
Vsum=Vsum+voltage;

static float Csum=0;
float Cave=0;
 float milli = pow(10, -3);
 float current = (voltage / sensitivity[model]);
 float current1 = current*milli;
Csum=Csum+current1;
count++;
Vave=Vsum/count;
Cave=Csum/count;


Serial.print("Average voltage: ");
Serial.print(Vave,2);
Serial.println("V");
Serial.print("Average current: ");
Serial.print(Cave,3);
Serial.println("A");
Serial.println("-----");
delay(3000);

}
```

Comment: part of the java code is properly formatted ... please format all of the code

Comment: So that means, that the data is correctly received by your java code (because you see it on systemout)? That means, that your Arduino and even your serial read java code is correct and your problem lies purely in setting the textarea. That doesn't have to do anything with Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

In you code : str = serialPort.readString();

Change this as ->   str = serialPort.readStringUntil('\n');